# Invalid Struct field values when passing it from managed to native code

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a following problem:

C++ code:

```
typedef struct
{
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
} XYZ;

double Sum(XYZ xyz)
{
  return xyz.x +xyz.y + xyz.z;
}
```

C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class XYZ
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
}
[DllImport("MyUnmanaged.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double Sum([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] XYZ xyz);
```

When I run following C# main:

```
XYZ1 xyz1 = new XYZ1 { x = 1f, y = 1f, z = 1f};
var x = MarchingCubesWrapper.Sum(xyz1);
```

I see that struct values did not passed to unmanaged environment well here is screenshot:

[image]

Could you tell me please what is the problem?

Comment: Should the C# XYZ be a struct rather than a class?

Comment: The attribute you have on your parameter doesn't look right.  I believe you should be leaving that out.  The function you're calling requires the structure, not a pointer to one.  Also it generally applies to `IntPtr` types and nothing else if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @dlev WOW ! 5 Hours I have wasted for this stupid mistake ! THANK YOU !!! :)

Comment: @dlev could you post your comment as answer?

Comment: @Sergey : Jeff is also correct -- in addition to making your managed `XYZ` a struct rather than a class, you need to get rid of `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `XYZ` as a `struct` rather than a `class`. It should then marshal correctly.